# How to display Edit Button only for last insertion Row id in php/mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a View Grid in Php. In this Edit button(like actions edit,delete icons) need to display only for last insertion row. Could you help me how to display like that.Here my code

```
<?php
$followup_details=mysql_query("select * from tbl_followup where school_id='$id' order by followup_id desc");
if(mysql_num_rows($followup_details))
{
?>
<form name="view-school" method="post" action="">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="table_txt">
  <tr class="table_txt2">
    <td width="7%">#</td>
        <td width="20%">Minutes Of Meeting</td>
    <td width="20%">Details</td>
    <td width="13%">Followup Status</td>
    <td width="10%">Next Meeting Date</td>
    <td width="10%">Actions</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
$slno=0;

while($followup=mysql_fetch_array($followup_details))
{
$slno++;

?>
<tr <?php if($slno%2==1) echo "class='table_txt3'"; else echo "class='table_txt4'"; ?>><td ><?php echo $slno;?></td>

<td ><?php echo ucwords($followup['mom']);?></td>
<td ><?php echo $followup['details'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo ucwords($followup['followup_status']);?></td>
<td ><?php echo $followup['next_meeting_date'];?></td>
 <td>
  <a href="#" class="edit-followup" data-reveal-id="editfollowup" data-animation="fade" id="<?php echo $followup['followup_id'];?>"><img src="images/edit_icon.png" alt="editicon" width="20" height="20" border="0" class="marg" /></a>

</td>
  <?php }
  ?>
```

My Edit Icon only have to display last insertion Row. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add it like you added the first table row?! Just after the loop?!

Comment: i added like that. But not getting exact output. @J2D8T

Comment: Must the edit icon display in a last table row or as part of the last row returned from the query?

Comment: missing `</tr>` at the end of your loop ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
$numRow= mysql_num_rows($followup_details)
```

and in your loop:

```
 <td>
<?php if($slno >= $numRow) { ?>
  <a href="#" class="edit-followup" data-reveal-id="editfollowup" data-animation="fade" id="<?php echo $followup['followup_id'];?>"><img src="images/edit_icon.png" alt="editicon" width="20" height="20" border="0" class="marg" /></a>
<?php } ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can print the edit buttons after you have generated the list, so it is not in the loop, but follows directly afterwards. Or you can check the number of rows before the loop. Then in the loop you put a counter from 1. When the counter is equal to the number of rows, you print the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get total no of records before while loop

```
  $total_records = mysql_num_rows($followup_details);
```

Now check in while loop

```
if($slno == $total_records -1 )
{
  ?>
    // this is final record
<a href="#" class="edit-followup" data-reveal-id="editfollowup" data-animation="fade" id="<?php echo $followup['followup_id'];?>"><img src="images/edit_icon.png" alt="editicon" width="20" height="20" border="0" class="marg" /></a>
  <?php
 }else{
   echo "&nbsp;";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check for `$slno` is 1. Because you are fetching records on descending order on `followup_id` so last inserted record will be on top (the first one).

```
<td>
  <?php
  if($slno===1):
  ?>
  <a href="#" class="edit-followup" data-reveal-id="editfollowup" data-animation="fade" id="<?php echo $followup['followup_id'];?>"><img src="images/edit_icon.png" alt="editicon" width="20" height="20" border="0" class="marg" /></a>
  <?php
  endif;
  ?>
</td>
```